# array value to array single characters

Tags: arrays, powershell

```psh
$array=@("blue","green","black")
[string]$input=Read-host "Input:"
$array[$input]
```

If I enter the number 1 into the input this gives no output. When I

```psh
Write-host $input
```

I get

```psh
System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple
```

What I'm looking to do next is:

```psh
$inputlist=@("0")
$inputlist += $array[$input]
```

But I seem to end up with an array where each element is a single letter. I would like them to be one string in `$inputlist[1]`.

Comment: Do you want the result to be `0, green` or `0, g, r, e, e, n`? `$inputlist = @("0"); $inputlist += $array[$val]` will already do the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Input` is an [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) and shouldn't be used in the way you do. Give your variable a different name and the problem will disappear:

```
PS C:\> $array = @('blue', 'green', 'black')
PS C:\> $val = Read-host 'Input'
Input: 2
PS C:\> $val
2
PS C:\> $val.GetType().FullName
System.String
PS C:\> $array[$val]
green
```

Splitting the string into an array of single characters can be handled by casting the string to a character array and then to a string array:

```
PS C:\> [string[]][char[]]$array[$val]
g
r
e
e
n
```

You'd still be able to append the characters to an array if you cast the string just to `char[]` (without casting it to `string[]` afterwards), but then you'd have an array with mixed types:

```
PS C:\> $inputList = @('0')
PS C:\> $inputList += [char[]]$array[$val]
PS C:\> $inputList
0
g
r
e
e
n
PS C:\> $inputList[0].GetType().FullName
System.String
PS C:\> $inputList[1].GetType().FullName
System.Char
```

If you want the entire string as the second element of the array, your existing code should already do that:

```
PS C:\> $inputList = @('0')
PS C:\> $inputList += $array[$val]
PS C:\> $inputList
0
green
```

Comment: Thats great, it solved the first problem of the
    Write-host $input
But i still have the issue of the $inputlist array storing each letter in single elements